# C#: Naming convention for Nested classes, and proper implementation?

Tags: c#, oop, inner-classes

I wonder if there is a standard for naming the "concrete" class and the instance.

For example, I have currently a class called Test and its instance is called is called Test as well. I think this is bad.

Is there some sort of standard to name the concrete class and its instance? The instance needs to be Test but the concrete I have no idea what to do; name it TestConcrete?

What does Microsoft do in this situation?

Basically the concrete class is ONLY for use in the Product class to support Nested classes, it will never be instantiated from outside.

Here is my class. I presume I am doing this correct? I am creating the instance of Test inside the constructor of Product.

I don't want to get into bad habits and I am going to be doing a lot of these, and Test (concrete) and Test (instance) is probably a bad idea!

```
public class Product    {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    private Test Test { get; set; }


    public Product()
    {
        Test = new Test();
    }
}
```

Comment: I name instances with small letter. For example: private Test test;

Comment: .NET guidelines are for properties to be PascalCased

Comment: Often, it does not matter much that the same name is used. However, in some situations it can cause conflict if there is some ambiguity. So in those cases, you either need to rename either the type or the property or qualify the type with its namespace. This is very different that what is done by C++. C# is more contextual and will usually be able to know if you want to use the type or the property depending of the context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not without precedent, I think you can find

```
  Color  Color { get; set; }
```

in the library, and some more like that.

But best way around it is to think of a more specific name, that is Domain driven. Something like

```
  private Test TestResults { get; set; }
```

or

```
  private TestData  Test { get; set; }
```

Comment: I like this, i have also been investigating how microsoft does it and have come up with - i think its better...  Test actually is a Test of product so the concrete class is called ProductTest and the property is Test so hence i have private ProductTest Test { get; set; }.

Answer (score 1):

These are my Guidelines:

```
public abstract class Test
{
    public void FooBar() // Method, capitalization, PascalCase
    {
         Person fatherFigure = new Person(); // Class instance, lowercase first letter, camelcase rest.

    }

    public string Name {get; set; } // Property, capitalization, PascalCase

    private string PrivateName {set; set; } // Private property, capitalization, camelcase

    public string someField; // Field, lowercase first letter, camelcase

    private string _someField; // Private member, prefix with _
}
```

These are only my own opinions. :)

Comment: Your convention for public fields doesn't follow Microsoft's recommended naming guidelines. Neither the fact that you *have* public fields, nor the fact that you camelCase them.

Comment: Well, as the end of my post states: "These are only my own opinions. :)" 

I'm not saying I use public fields, but if it happens for some reason, that is how I would name them :)